# Intellij's auto insertion conflicting with vim mode

Tags: vim, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, vi

So Intellij/Eclipse have this nice functionality where typing a `'` or `(` automatically inserts the closing `'` or `)`.

While this is great in normal operation, using the Vim mode/vim keybindings makes this more of a pain.

So for example I am typing a function which takes 2 strings as an argument:

```
 new MyObject('arg1','arg2');
```

when I type the opening `'`, Intellij will automatically insert the closing `'`. Now when I have to type the second argument, I will have to:

1. Press Esc to leave insert mode
2. Use `l` to move caret after the closing `'`
3. Enter back into insert mode.

Not to mention this issue occurs when you have to type the semi colon at the end of the function call (to skip the closing `)`).

This seems like too many operations. Moving your hand to press escape breaks the flow of typing and the auto completion of intellj here causes more hassle than productivity.

Is there a better way around this or am I stuck with just disabling this particular auto insertion stuff?

Comment: The only point of this feature is to prevent you from forgetting a closing `'")}]`, *not* to save typing: you get the security but you always need to get out of the pair in one way or another so you end up either typing over the closing character or moving with the right arrow or whatever. Whether you think the risk is worth the hassle is up to you. I think it doesn't and I disable it when possible.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if turning Settings/Editor/Smart keys/Insert pair quote off helps